# WordPress site not working on main domain

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I've uploaded the WordPress website on a server. and if try to access the site using the main domain it shows the screen shown below. and if I update the site URL in the database with a subdomain and use subdomain then the site's homepage opens but cant switch to any other page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the dns are correctly propagated, especially the nameservers.
Try to change permalink settings and flush cache on your browser.